# Capturing objects in Django Url

Tags: python, django, url

Suppose I have this model:

```
Class animals(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

and I make 3 objects of it, say ob1, ob2, ob3 with ob1.name = cat, ob2.name = dog, ob3.name = cow

Now if I have a url like this `www.domain.com/cat`or `www.domain.com/dog`, How to capture `/cat` or `/dog`from the url and check against the names of objects of class animal?

I am trying to implement a view function that takes a parameter from the url, eg: object.name, and execute according to that object.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

> It’s possible to use named regular-expression groups to capture URL
>   bits and pass them as keyword arguments to a view.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<name>\w+)/$', 'my_view'),)
```

views.py:

```
def my_view(request, name=None):
    # get a model instance
    animal = animals.objects.get(name=name)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to detect objects from urls? im trying something like this in urls.py, `url(animal.objects.value_list('name'), include('animalapp.urls')`. I want to match the `/cat` or `/dog` from url and match it with animal.objects.value_list('name') list. Is this possible?

Comment: @HHH how does this answer not provide what you're looking for?

Comment: Generally catch all pattern like this `url(r'^(?P<name>\w+)/$', 'my_view')` is bad idea. If it is possible change it to something like `url(r'^animal/(?P<name>\w+)/$', 'my_view')`. Otherwise if you must have it `/cat`, `/cow`, etc. you may have to move part of your url routing logic in `my_view(request, name)` which also is bad idea